# Formatting text in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am absolute beginner to Shell scripting. 
My task is to make a script, which will show functions used in a file (caller and callee).
I have used objdump, grep, awk etc. to get this output:

```
000000000040090d <usage>:
000000000040095d <failure>:
  400970:   e8 98 ff ff ff          callq  40090d <usage>
000000000040097f <strton>:
  4009bc:   e8 9c ff ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
00000000004009c6 <main>:
  400a0e:   e8 6c ff ff ff          callq  40097f <strton>
  400a26:   e8 32 ff ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
  400a41:   e8 39 ff ff ff          callq  40097f <strton>
  400a59:   e8 ff fe ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
  400a9a:   e8 be fe ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
  400aae:   e8 cc fe ff ff          callq  40097f <strton>
  400ac2:   e8 b8 fe ff ff          callq  40097f <strton>
  400ad1:   e8 87 fe ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
  400afe:   e8 fe 01 00 00          callq  400d01 <set_timeout>
  400b1c:   e8 3c fe ff ff          callq  40095d <failure>
  400b26:   e8 19 00 00 00          callq  400b44 <print_fib_upto>
  400b37:   e8 89 00 00 00          callq  400bc5 <print_ackermann>
```

Okay, the result should look like this:

```
failure -> usage
strton -> failure
main -> failure
main -> print_ackermann
main -> print_fib_upto
main -> set_timeout
main -> strton
```

But I have no idea how to accomplish it. I'd know how to do it in C, etc, but not here. I think this is the right pseudo-code.

```
If (end of line == ">:")
         caller == last column;
         while (end of line == ">") {
                   callee == last column;
                   echo "$caller -> $callee"
         }
```

Can anyone tell me, how to write this in BASH? Thank you very much, Maybe it's a silly question, but I don't know anyting about shell yet.

Comment: Curious. You've been directed to write this in *pure* BASH? If not, then why not use `C`? If so, it's unusual to be forbidden to use `awk` and `sed`, which are both written in `C`.

Comment: I do IT school, this is our project, that's why. We have shell subject. And we can use awk and sed.

Comment: I think you can do everything you want by piping the output of `objdump` into a short `sed` script, obviating the need for `grep`, `awk`, etc. See below. Works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F'[<>:]+' 'NF==3{p=$(NF-1); next} {print p, "->", $(NF-1)}' file
failure -> usage
strton -> failure
main -> strton
main -> failure
main -> strton
main -> failure
main -> failure
main -> strton
main -> strton
main -> failure
main -> set_timeout
main -> failure
main -> print_fib_upto
main -> print_ackermann
```

Comment: Wow, looks quite complicated to me, but makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash    
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *:) caller=$line; continue;;
        *)  echo "$caller $line";;
    esac
done < <(sed 's/.*</</' < caldata) | sed 's/[<>]//g;s/:/ -> /' | sort -u
```

produces:

```
failure ->  usage
main ->  failure
main ->  print_ackermann
main ->  print_fib_upto
main ->  set_timeout
main ->  strton
strton ->  failure
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be easier with `awk`, but I interpreted your pseudocode directly into bash.

```
while read; do # If not given an argument `read` puts the line into `REPLY`
  case $REPLY in # Use a case expression for pattern matching.
    *>:) caller="${REPLY##*<}"
         caller="${caller%>:}" # Parameter expansions to strip off unwanted parts of the line.
         ;;
    *>) callee="${REPLY##*<}"
        callee="${callee%>}"
        ;;
  esac
  echo "$caller -> $callee"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF==2 {
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $NF)
    caller = $NF
    next
}
{
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $NF)
    map[caller,$NF]++
}
END {
    for(calls in map) {
        n = split(calls, tmp, SUBSEP)
        print tmp[1]" -> "tmp[2]
    }
}' file
main -> printackermann
main -> settimeout
strton -> failure
main -> printfibupto
main -> failure
failure -> usage
main -> strton
```

**or**

```
$ awk '
NF==2 {
    for(keys in map) 
        print map[keys]" -> "keys;
    delete map
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $NF)
    caller = $NF
    next
}
{
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $NF)
    map[$NF] = caller
}
END {
    for(keys in map)  
        print map[keys]" -> "keys
}' file
failure -> usage
strton -> failure
main -> strton
main -> settimeout
main -> printackermann
main -> printfibupto
main -> failure
```

Answer (score 2):

The *whole thing* can be done with `sed` reasonably easily, negating the need for preprocessing with `grep`, etc. The following isn't perfect (you may have to tweak regexes and what is/isn't considered a match), but it should break the back of it.

```
#!/bin/bash

symbol='[_A-Za-z][_@A-Za-z0-9]\+'

objdump -d "$1" | sed -n "
/^[0-9a-f]\+ <\(${symbol}\)>:/{ # Match symbol in header
    s//\1/                      # Symbol only in pattern space
    h                           # Save symbol to hold space
    : loop                      # (until empty line)
    n                           # Next line
    /^$/!{                      # If not an empty line
        # Try matching 'callq' line and extract symbol:
        /^[:[:space:][:xdigit:]]\+callq[^<]\+<\($symbol\)>/{
            s//\1/              # Symbol only in pattern space
            G                   # Append hold space to pattern space
            # Swap words in pattern space, adding separator:
            s/\($symbol\)[[:space:]]\($symbol\)/\2 -> \1/g
            p                   # Print pattern space:
        }
        b loop                  # Try next line
    }
}"
```

Comment: As a dance of an crazy toothpicks. :) Love it, +1

Comment: @jm666: It looks worse than it is, but I admit it'd be hairy if it was all on one line with no comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but for pure bash, it could be done as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    [[ "$line" =~ \<(.*)\>\:$ ]] && caller=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    [[ "$line" =~ \<(.*)\>$ ]] && callee=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    [ -n $caller -a -n $callee ] && echo "$caller -> $callee";
    callee=""
done < $1
```

The `[[ expr ]] &&` means test expr, and if true, run what's afterwards.  The `=~` is a regexp matcher, where the value in the `()`'s is stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.